# How to get spinner hint image in Android?

Tags: android, image, android-spinner

I am new in Android. I want to make my spinner looks like this, where crust and adds on are given.

But I am not been able to put the hint image on the spinner; thought my spinner shape is as good as it shows in the pic, the only problem is with the image hint.

[image]

Here is my edited XML for this layout: here only 1 spinner with the image is showing that too the curves are not that good.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/desimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/h1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Chicken Pizza Small"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/h2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Chicken Pizza Small Combo"
            android:textColor="#8c8181"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/quant"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:text="Quantity"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:background="@drawable/stroke_button"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/incr"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="#FFA726"
                    android:textSize="25dp" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/value"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:text="1" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#c0c0c0" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/decr"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="#FFA726"
                    android:textSize="25dp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="SL"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="S"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/m"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="M"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/L"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="l"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/f"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:buttonTint="#c0c0c0"
                android:text="F"
                android:textColor="#8c8181"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#c0c0c0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_gray">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:src="@drawable/spinpres" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/stroke_button"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:src="@drawable/spinpres" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke_button"
            android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin1">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:lines="5"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColor="#c0c0c0" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/canc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton2"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ok"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:text="Ok"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this is spinner_selecter.xml where image is there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinpres" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinpres" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do same by using custom layout.

Here is code for spinner in layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border_gray">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border_gray">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spin_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Create a xml file in drawable folder named -border_gray.xml and here is code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="@color/white" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/gray" />

<corners
    android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

Now change Image source according to your need.

Comment: your code works only for single spinner ..getting bit confused plz see my edited xml layout

Comment: Check updated answer, you have to change accordingly your need now

Comment: yes i ahve changed that specially border_grey layout...apart from that ..i got the solution ..thx alot...

Comment: Your welcome, and don't forget to up-vote for answer if it helps you.

Comment: Clicked on up arrow above the green tick  to change count form 0 to 1.

Comment: oh is it also neccessary,i didnt knew tht

Answer (score 0):

Spinner

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/To_Units"
    style="@style/spinner_style" />
```

style.xml

```
<style name="spinner_style">
      <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>
      <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
      <item name="android:popupBackground">#DFFFFFFF</item>
 </style>
```

gradient_spinner.xml (in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#B3BBCC" android:startColor="#E8EBEF" android:type="linear" />

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:gravity="right|center_vertical" 
                android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_arrow">
            </item>
        </layer-list>
   </item>
</selector>
```

Download any down arrow image and use it